# how to combine angularjs dynamic text input with d3js-created svg circles for filtering

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg, d3.js

I have a d3js bubble chart with many circles.  They have an `id` that corresponds to a city name.

```
var cities = ["Toronto", "London", "Paris"];
```

and I have a standard `input` box in html.

```
<input id="searchBox" onchange="checkFilled()" />
```

The `checkFilled()` function:

```
function checkFilled() {

  var inputVal = document.getElementById("searchBox").value;
  var circleId = d3.select("#" + inputVal + "");

  cities.forEach(function ( city ) {

      if (inputVal == "") {

          circleId.style("fill", "white");

      }
      else if ( inputVal == city ){

          circleId.style("fill", "red");

      }
  })

}
```

This works (the fill is changed) but is clunky: case-sensitive, requires hitting enter, won't revert when text removed.

My goal is to make it dynamic.  The fill should change as the text is added/removed in real time, much like this example: http://jsfiddle.net/sravikiran/eBcaB/5/light/  where sorting an html table using angular js input is demonstrated.

Ideally the sorting behaviour can be replicated on svg elements created by d3js or javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

my 2 cents

```
<input id="searchBox" onkeyup="checkFilled()" />

function checkFilled() {
  var inputVal = document.getElementById("searchBox").value;
  var sel = d3.selectAll("#" + circlesContainer + "").filter(function(d) { return this.id.match(new RegExp('^'+inputVal, 'i')); });

  d3.selectAll("#" + circlesContainer).style('fill', 'white');
  sel.attr('fill', 'red');
}
```